# A finite group that is neither solvable or simple

Tags: group-theory

I've been struggling coming up with an example of a finite group that is neither solvable or simple. Can anyone please help?

It would be better if you could provide some general guidance for problems like this. For example, which family of groups to look at first, etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: $S_5$, the symmetric group over 5 elements is the smallest example, I think.

Comment: @Crostul Yes, this is a smallest example, but there are other examples of the same order, for instance $A_5\times C_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ and $H$ be non-abelian simple groups, like $A_n,n\ge 5$, or $PSL(n,q)$ for $n\ge 3$. Then the direct product $G\times H$ is not simple and also not solvable. More generally, the semidirect product $G\rtimes_{\phi}H$ is neither simple nor solvable, since $G$ is a non-trivial proper normal subgroup.
Furthermore, the semidrect product between a simple group and an abelian group is neither simple nor solvable, for example,
$$
S_n=A_n\rtimes C_2, n\ge 5.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Could you please provide a little more detail on why the given groups are not solvable?

Comment: Every subgroup of a solvable group is solvable. However, these groups obviously have a non-solvable subgroup. For example, $S_n$ has the subgroup $A_n$, which is not solvable for all $n\ge 5$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Take the product of a simple group and a commutative like $A_n\times S_2, n>5$ or $S_n, n>5$. If $n>5, A_n$ the subgroup of even permuations is simple, and $S_n$ is not simple since $[S_n,S_n]=A_n$.